# Set the ship's roll in sea waves in accordance with the roll spectrum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I need to set the ship's roll equation at sea (side or keel roll) in accordance with the real roll spectrum (Jonswap, Pearson Moskvin).
I can't relate the wave spectrum and the ship's tilt time function.
Please point me to the literature where I could find all this.

Now I use the harmonic law of my ship's roll, but it does not allow me to carry out my experiments sufficiently and does not correspond to the real roll.